# compare and print 2 columns from 2 files in awk ou perl

Tags: awk

I have 2 files with 2 million lines.
I need to compare 2 columns in 2 different files and I want to print the lines of the 2 files where there are equal items.
this awk code works, but it does not print lines from the 2 files:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {a[$3]; next}$3 in a' file1.txt file2.txt
```

file1.txt

```
0001 00000001 084010800001080
0001 00000010 041140000100004
```

file2.txt

```
2451 00000009 401208008004000
2451 00000010 084010800001080
```

desired output:

```
file1[$1]-file2[$1] file1[$2]-file2[$2] $3 ( same on both files )

0001-2451 00000001-00000010 084010800001080
```

how to do this in awk or perl?

Comment: So for 2,000,000 lines in 2 files, you need to compare each line to each other, and print if there is a match in col 3? That's a pretty big task. 2*10^12 comparisons? You might want to consider performance options

Comment: Are you comparing the numbers stringwise or numerically? E.g. is `10` the same as `00000010`, or not. Are you sorting the print in numerical order, or the order in which the matches appear? E.g. could it be `2451-0001` instead?

Comment: If you have multiple matches, would you combine all the lines in the print, or print different "ranges"? E.g. `0001-2451`, `0001-4201`, `0001-9999`, etc.

Comment: Is every `$3` value unique within each file? If not please include at least 1 duplicate case that matches across both files in your sample input/output.

Comment: @TLP it's just a hash lookup while reading the 2nd file, it'll be fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `$3` values are unique within each input file as shown in your sample input/output:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    foos[$3] = $1
    bars[$3] = $2
    next
}
$3 in foos {
    print foos[$3] "-" $1, bars[$3] "-" $2, $3
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1.txt file2.txt
0001-2451 00000001-00000010 084010800001080
```

I named the arrays `foos[]` and `bars[]` as I don't know what the first 2 columns of your input actually represent - choose a more meaningful name.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Fair warning
I haven't tested it yet with millions of lines.

```
awk '
FNR == NR{
  arr1[$3]=$0
  next
}
($3 in arr1){
  split(arr1[$3],arr2)
  print (arr2[1]"-"$1,arr2[2]"-"$2,$3)
  delete arr2
}
' file1.txt file2.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                  ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR == NR{                             ##checking condition which will be TRUE when first Input_file is being read.
  arr1[$3]=$0                          ##Creating arr1 array with value of $1 OFS $2 and $3
  next                                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($3 in arr1){                          ##checking if $3 is present in arr1 then do following.
  split(arr1[$3],arr2)             ##Splitting value of arr1 into arr2.
  print (arr2[1]"-"$1,arr2[2]"-"$2,$3) ##printing values as per requirement of OP.
  delete arr2                          ##Deleting arr2 array here.
}
' file1.txt file2.txt                  ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have two massive files, you may want to use `sort`, `join` and `awk` to produce your output without having to have the first file mostly in memory.

Based on your example, this pipe would do that:

```
join -1 3 -2 3 <(sort -k3 -n file1) <(sort -k3 -n file2) | awk '{printf("%s-%s %s-%s %s\n",$2,$4,$3,$5,$1)}'
```

Prints:

```
0001-2451 00000001-00000010 084010800001080
```

Answer (score 0):

If your files are that big, you might want to avoid storing the data in memory. It's a whole lot of comparisons, 2 million lines times 2 million lines = 4 * 10<sup>12</sup> comparisons.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $file1 = shift;
my $file2 = shift;

open my $fh1, "<", $file1 or die "Cannot open '$file1': $!";

while (<$fh1>) {
    my @F = split;
    open my $fh2, "<", $file2 or die "Cannot open '$file2': $!";
    # for each line of file1 file2 is reopened and read again
    while (my $cmp = <$fh2>) {
        my @C = split ' ', $cmp;
        if ($F[2] eq $C[2]) {       # check string equality
            say "$F[0]-$C[0] $F[1]-$C[1] $F[2]";
        }
    }
}
```

With your rather limited test set, I get the following output:

```
0001-2451 00000001-00000010 084010800001080
```

Answer (score 0):

Python: tested with 2.000.000 rows each file

```
d = {}
with open('1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('2.txt', 'r') as f2:
  for line in f1:
    if not line: break
    c0,c1,c2 = line.split()
    d[(c2)] = (c0,c1)

  for line in f2:
    if not line: break
    c0,c1,c2 = line.split()
    if (c2) in d: print("{}-{} {}-{} {}".format(d[(c2)][0], c0, d[(c2)][1], c1, c2))

$ time python3 comapre.py
1001-2001 10000001-20000001 224010800001084
1042-2013 10000042-20000013 224010800001096

real    0m3.555s
user    0m3.234s
sys     0m0.321s
```